# Load a certain page when entering a website in Magento

Tags: magento

I made a welcome page on my shop with the link www.myshop.com/welcome
but my base page is still www.myshop.com
I want to load the www.myshop.com/welcome page as soon as I enter the page first. That basically means that if I type in www.myshop.com it will load the www.myshop.com/welcome page.

I tried to change the base url to www.myshop.com/welcome, but that messes up my backend and I have to change it back via phpMyAdmin.

Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Does "www.myshop.com/welcome" is created with CMS page?

From administrador, Menu Sistem > Configuration > Web > Default Pages

Select your page in 'CMS Homepage'

[image]